# Does the Assassin take damage when he uses Vanish?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, assassin

The 4th Edition Assassin class has a Level 6 Utility Power Called Vanish:

> **Encounter - Immediate Reaction**
>   **Personal**
>   **Keywords:** Shadow, Teleportation
>   **Trigger:** You are hit by an attack.
>   **Effect:** You become invisible until the start of your next turn, and you teleport up to your speed.

My question is: does the assassin take damage from the attack that triggered Vanish? Or do they get to Vanish after a successful attack roll but before damage is dealt?

Interested to hear ruling interpretations on this.

Comment: Does the Assassin take damage when he uses Vanish? - Only if taken internally...badum-tish!

Comment: It is unfortunate that the ability wasn't worded: `Trigger: You take damage from an attack` to clarify this is in fact after the damage. The ability would be WAY too powerful if it allowed you to avoid damage and become invisible 1/enc. As a DM, I would probably rule against it avoiding damage even if it said it in clearer language, for balance issues. You'll find similar abilities that do actually let you avoid an attack as an Immediate Interrupt, but they let the enemy re-target a different creature with the attack, or force them to hit one of their allies (as a daily power).

Comment: @Corion: There isn't much clarification needed on the power. Immediate Reactions (after) and Immediate Interrupts (before) are clearly defined in the rules. Since Vanish is a Reaction, it happens after the attack is resolved. Also, it is entirely possible to take no damage from an attack (several attacks don't even deal damage), so Vanish's trigger makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 8):

If an attack successfully hits you, it will then deal damage. The two are linked. In addition, Immediate Reactions occur after the trigger that allows it to be used resolves. I think you are instead thinking about the "when you are attacked" trigger, often an Immediate Interrupt, which would allow you to use a power to avoid the attack altogether once the enemy declared it.

Comment: The trigger is "you are hit" which means that the damage definitely happens or the power didn't. And it's a reaction which means it happens *after* the triggering effect rather than before.

Comment: @waxeagle: I clarified a few things, and mentioned immediate interrupts. I haven't touched a 4e source book in a couple years, so if something seems off let me know.

Comment: "If an attack successfully hits you, it will then deal damage." Not necessarily. Immediate Interrupt effects exist that trigger on a hit and prevent or attempt to prevent the effects of the hit (e.g. raising defenses against the attack, switching the target, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

The Vanish Power is an immediate *reaction*. Reactions always happen after the triggering action has been affecting its target.

Would this power have been an immediate interruption instead, the *trigger* line would also have been something on the lines of "someone attacks you".

Comment: ^This. There's a really easy way to know whether something happens either before or after a triggered action. *Reaction* means you react to it after the fact. *Interrupt* means it happens before.

Comment: "...the *trigger* line would also have been something on the lines of "someone attacks you"." Not necessarily. Immediate Interrupt effects exist that trigger on a hit and prevent or attempt to prevent the effects of the hit (e.g. raising defenses against the attack, switching the target, etc.).